# Django, form/widgets/input.html problems

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm trying to change the Django input widgets, in theory, i just need to copy the path from the GitHub Django project, but for some reason it's not using mine, is just using the default input

[image]

Django path

[image]

my path.

I don't know what the matter is, I already tried with another browser, and deleting the browser cache.